# Get user access token from Graph Api Explore facebook and extend it

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know how to get short-term user access token then extend it to long-term access token (facebook) when i have my own app id and app secret. But now I want to get and extend the access token provided by Graph Api Explorer. How can I do it ?
If we do it manually, we get an access token from Graph Api Explorer but its short term and will expires in about 1 hours, how can I make it a long-term access token?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. To extend the Access Tokens, you must utilize an `app_id` as well as an `app_secret`. I assume you don't have the `app_secret` of the Graph Explorer, so this might get difficult.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Comment: I understood this problem, but are there any workingaround solutions

Comment: No, and why is everybody always asking for workarounds if this is by design?! First, you should ask yourself why it's necessary for you to use Graph Explorer at all. It's just another app. What do you expect from using it?

Comment: I want to search fb user by name, when i use a user access token which is generated by App, it returns a list of results that contains Name and Id but the id here is app scope id and I cant use this. I need a real facebook user id when I use FB Graph to search. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need the global id? You can perform every request also on the app-scoped id...

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/298434840343050 doesn't work, because it is App scope user id, I get this id by using access token generated by a FB App, https://graph.facebook.com/299768896876311 works because it is real facebook user id and i get this id by using access token generated by Graph Api Explorer. I need a global id

Comment: You can only use app-scoped ids with the app they have been generated with. If you try it with another app it will fail. End of story. There are tens of thousands app developer using those...

Answer (score 0):

I still have this issue and Tobi not understood the problem.
The Facebook Access Tokens are really problematic most of times and this is one of the bigger issue.

I have a facebook stream plugin where user can show their personal profile posts.
But the only access token that work is the one generated by Graph API Explorer and this can not be extended. Any other access token associated to an APP will not work.

Is incredible that Facebook not have a tool to allow users to generate an access token for access their personal informations.
Currently there is not any working solution. Incredible.